# KDE Neon cannot run Vulkan apps!

Tags: intel-graphics, steam, kde5, vulkan

I've installed lastest Intel graphics driver for Linux and I installed Dota 2 with Vulkan support. But I cannot run it, it always says "Failed to initialize Vulkan please make sure your Driver and GPU support Vulkan".

Comment: Does your Intel graphics support it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)#Compatibility